# Looping a script for every page of PDF with python

Tags: python, loops, pdf

Just started learning python for automating one specific and tedious task at work. Perhaps someone could help a noobie? :)

So I am reading a multi-page PDF file with pdfplumber. The data is identically arranged text data on every page. From this data I need to compare one piece of data (type) with other piece of data (size). It works fine but I need to manually change the page number. I wish to loop the script for every page and make a list of the results and I have no idea how to do this.

Here is an example of my code:

```
`import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open("typesize.pdf") as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()

print(page)

for row in text.split('\n'):
    if row.startswith('Type'):
    type = row.strip()[-1:]
print("Type", type)

for row in text.split('\n'):
    if row.startswith('Size'):
    size = row.split()[-1]
print("Size", size)

if type == 'X' and size == '1':
    print("OK")
elif type == 'Y' and size == '2':
    print("OK")
elif type == 'Z' and size == '3':
    print("OK")
else: print("INCORRECT")`
```

And here is the result I get:

```
Page:1
Type X
Size 1
OK
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used `pdfplumber` before, but looking at the documentation, `pdfplumber.PDF.pages` is just a list of page objects, so you should be able to iterate over them with a simple for loop. I have no idea what your code does, but I would change it to something like the following:

```
import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open("typesize.pdf") as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        current_page_text = page.extract_text()
        for row in current_page_text.splitlines():
            if row.startswith("Type"):
                special_type = row.strip()[-1:]
                print(f"Type: {special_type}")
            elif row.startswith("Size"):
                size = row.split()[-1]
                print(f"Size: {size}")
```

I've renamed your `type` variable to `special_type`, because `type` is a reserved keyword in Python, which you should not be using for a variable identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the tip. So my code is supposed to spot mistakes in PDF by extracting two sets of data from each page and compare these two sets with each other. So for instance if variable "Type" has value "X", the other variable on the page that is "Size" has to have value "1", or else there is a mistake in the data.